# Get the exact SQL query that get_posts() generated

Tags: get-posts, sql

I am working on a WordPress that someone else started and then disappeared. She created a few custom content types and variables using different plugins and I now want to access the data sets in the functions she created for her template.

```
$args = array(
                'suppress_filters' => 0,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                'sort_column' => 'post_title',
                'post_type' => 'inst',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$content = get_posts($args);
```

I have been looking around and different findings suggested using the following variable to get the SQL used:

```
echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;
```

However, what this returns is not the query that shows the post data appearing on the page. When I run that in MySQL directly, it returns exactly 1 result and I think it's the whole page? Because I defined two datasets and there are two fields appearing on the page but only 1 row in the query that's echoed by above line.

I need to know the exact attributes of the `WP_Query` object in $content but `var_dump($content)` also doesn't contain the fields I defined. I need to get the image that's in the content typeset, but I can only get the name of the set accessing `$content->post_title`.

Is there a way to dig into what `get_posts()` gets from the database and how I can access the attributes I need?

Comment: Try a query monitor plugin. There are a few different ones available and they'll show you every database query being run on a particular page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `get_posts()` function creates an instance of WP_Query inside the function and simply returns the array of results. This WP_Query instance doesn't override the `global $wp_query` and is out of scope by the time you need it. In short, I don't see a way how you can get the requested SQL via `get_posts()`.

An alternative is to simply create your own instance of WP_Query and pass your `get_posts()` arguments to it:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'inst',
    'post_status'       => 'publish'
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'order'             => 'ASC',           // sort_order
    'orderby'           => 'post_title',    // sort_column
) );
```

That will give you the whole WP_Query object where you can output the SQL:

```
$query_sql = $query->request;
```

---

Finally, if you're already creating a WP_Query you don't need the `get_posts()` call at all at that point.

```
if( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();
        the_content();

    }

    // Reset the global $wp_query to what it was originally.
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: I will try the request like you suggested. As for the get_post part I don't know yet how she designed her template in detail, it's a multi page setup with child themes that use some sort of onepager and she created a few functions. I will rather leave it as it is when it works.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to get the SQL query generated by the get_posts() function by using the 'query' [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/) (since you are not suppressing the filters in you query, the hook will be fired prior to execution of the final SQL query,

```
add_filter('query', 'get_sql');
function get_sql($query){
  //check if this is your query,
  if(strpos($query, "'inst'")>0){
    //this is your query....print it to your log file to debug it.
    error_log($query);
  }
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does exactly what the OP wanted.